# Django: What is the most efficient method to query and aggregate based on date + foreign key

Tags: django

i have a model with some fields, such as that:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField()
  related = models.ForeignKey(Related)
  ...
```

i want to create a report which takes a start and end date and summarizes the total number of records for each date + for each date, the number of records for each value of related.

--- EDIT 1 ---- 
Example: lets say that i have the following records in Foo:

```
[date, related, ...]
[3-3-13, val1, ...]
[3-3-13, val1, ...]
[3-3-13, val2, ...]
[3-4-13, val1, ...]
[3-4-13, val3, ...]
[3-4-13, val3, ...]
[3-4-13, val3, ...]
```

i want to get:

```
3-3-13: total=3, val1=2, val2=1
3-4-13: total=4, val1=1, val3=3
```

--- End of EDIT 1 ----

i want this to be efficient with minimal hits on the Dbase. My intention it to have 2 hits on the Dbase:

1. to extract all Foo objects in the required dates
2. All related objects that are related to a record in #1
   Once i have those in memory, i dont think i need to hit the Dbase at all.

i tried the following:

```
objects = Foo.objects.filter(date__gte=start).values_list('date','related') # Dbase query 1
objects = objects.filter(date__lte=end) 
related_list = objects.values_list('related',flat=True)
rel_objects = Related.objects.filter(id__in=related_list) # Dbase query 2
cur_date = start
while cur_date <= end:
  cur_obj = objects.filter(date__startswith=cur_date)
  cur_related = rel_objects.filter(id__in=cur_obj.values_list('related'))
  for r in cur_related:
    count = len(cur_obj.values('related').filter(related=r))
    ...
```

The problem is that i see hits to the Dbase every time i enter the internal loop (for r in cur_related).

Also - i keep changing the values_list and im not sure how i can do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Model Description

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  post_date = models.DateTimeField()
  related = models.ForeignKey(Related)

related_info = Foo.objects.filter(post_date__get=start_date, \
    post_date__lte = end_date).extra(select = {'temp_date':'date(post_date)'}). \
    values('temp_date').annotate(count = Count('related'))


#related_info is [('post_date','related_count'),...]
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i wanted - i edited the question with an example of what i want to get

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

With that definition

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField()
  related = models.ForeignKey(Related, related_name="foos")

#1)
objects = Foo.objects.filter(Q(date__gte=start) & Q(date__lte=end))

#2)
related = Related.objects.filter(foos__in=objects)
count = related.count()
```

Please, test it and tell me.

Comment: in your answer i have a single result "count" but i want to have the count for every date and every related value for each date.

Comment: i edited the question with an example of what i want to have - hope it is clearer now